# Show that there exists a subspace $W \subset \mathcal{P}(4)$ such that $\mathcal{P}(4) = \mathcal{U}(4) \oplus W.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{U}(4)$ be a subspace of $\mathcal{P}(4)$ consisting of polynomials that are even functions. Show that there exists a subspace $W \subset \mathcal{P}(4)$ such that $$\mathcal{P}(4) = \mathcal{U}(4) \oplus W.$$

Additionally,
I know that a function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is even if $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$.

And that a function can also be expressed as the sum of an odd an even function $$f(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal{U}(4)=Span(1,x^2, x^4), \mathcal{W}=Span(x,x^3)$$

Comment: Thanks! :) Clarified everything.

Comment: My pleasure, happy to help.